# to create error log excel file in php

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have created the error log text file to show the error by using the following code

```
$file_path = FCPATH . "assets/log/error.txt";
   $myfile = fopen($file_path , "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
   $txt = 'pls check error for'.' '. $id."\r\n";
   fwrite($myfile, $txt);
   fclose($myfile);
```

Now i have to create the same error log file in excel with one column as S.No and other column with field name and error as shown in below message instead of showing only the message.Pls help me to reslve the above issue.

[image]

Comment: So have you tried using phpexcel?

Comment: you can create a csv file and that can be opened with excel (that if you don't want to use an external library) ...use the http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: I agree with using CSV unless there is a real need for xlsx. Most of the times Excel will open the file just like an Excel file with the lines exploded anyways. And csvs are easier to "build" and bug test and are smaller in size than xlsx file a.

Comment: Also you need to explain what you mean with the text below the code. Maybe it's just me but I don't understand any of it.

Comment: Above i have given the screen shot for example

Comment: Still very poorly explained. Vote for close.